# Purpose of a BlockChain in local wallet application

Tags: wallet, blockchain, bitcoin-core

I have installed the BitCoin wallet application on my PC, so that I can cold store my BitCoin. It's "Synchronizing with the network" and has 272 weeks of BC left to download (painfully slow!!)

What I want to know is, why do I need to download the BC in order to send/receive funds from my wallet. Is this absolutely necessary?

Answer (score 1):

The [blockchain](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Block_chain) is the full record of all Bitcoin transactions. Without it, we wouldn't know how much each address is able to spend.

There are [some clients](https://bitcoin.org/en/choose-your-wallet) (called lightweight clients) that rely on their peers' blockchains while others like Bitcoin Core (sometimes called a full client/node) store the blockchain themselves. If you choose a full client, you should expect to download and store the blockchain (~21 GB currently). You can speed up the initial sync by download bootstrap.dat from a torrent, [as instructed here](https://bitcoin.org/en/download).

What you're describing, though, is not [cold storage](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Cold_storage)! Cold storage means that the keys are only accessible via offline means, like a piece of paper, or a computer that is never connected to the Internet.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll certainly take a look at the bootstrap.dat torrent. In terms of cold storage I intend to encrypt the wallet.dat files and burn them to a cd and remove them from my pc.